# Autocomplete não mostra resultados no input na View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocompletar

Eu já vi outros casos em algumas respostas aqui, tentei seguir os passos de outras respostas e não adiantou em nada! Estou com uma dúvida, esta é minha primeira vez que utilizo **`autocomplete`** do `jquery`, sou novo em **asp.net mvc**!

Eu queria que ao usuário digitar no `textbox` ou `input`, de acordando com ele digitando já aparecesse o resultado daquilo que ele está procurando no campo, o que me levou ao autocomplete, segui alguns passos na internet, mas como é minha primeira vez usando ele, estou com dúvida, ele não retorna os dados do banco, porque o que eu quero retornar do banco é o **CLIENTE** pelo **IDCLIENTE**, a instrução **SQL** eu já tenho!
Meu problema e que ele não está trazendo ao digitar não aparece nada!

> Está é a minha `View`com a função **Jquery** no íncio da página:

```
<script>    
    $(function () {
        $("#cliente").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetClientesJson",)',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="widget widget-table action-table">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
                <h3>Vendas Por Produtos</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /widget-header -->
            <div class="widget-content">
                @if (ViewData["reportvendas"] == null)
                {
                    <form action="#" id="myform" method="post">
                        <div class="login-fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <table style="margin:10px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Data Venda:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="inicio" name="inicio" class="login requerido birth" style="width:90px" /></td>
                                        <td>Ate</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="fim" name="fim" class="login requerido birth" style="width:90px" /></td>
                                        <td>Agrupado</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="agrupamento" name="agrupamento" class="login" style="width:200px">
                                                <option value="grupo">Grupo</option>
                                                <option value="vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                                                <option value="cliente">Cliente</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Grupo:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="grupo" name="grupo" class="login" style="width:200px">
                                                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                                @foreach (var item in combo.Grupo().OrderBy(ordem => ordem.DESCRICAO))
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@item.IDPRODGRUPO">@item.DESCRICAO</option>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Sub Grupo:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="subgrupo" name="subgrupo" class="login" style="width:200px">
                                                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                                @foreach (var item in combo.SubGrupo().OrderBy(ordem2 => ordem2.DESCRICAO))
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@item.IDSUBGRUPO">@item.DESCRICAO</option>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Fabricante:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="fabricante" name="fabricante" class="login" style="width:200px">
                                                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                                @foreach (var item in combo.Fabricante().OrderBy(m => m.NOMERAZAO))
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@item.IDFABRICANTE">@item.NOMERAZAO</option>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Codigo de Barras</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="codigoinicio" name="codigoinicio" class="login" style="width:90px" /></td>
                                        <td>a</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="codigofim" name="codigofim" class="login" style="width:90px" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>


                            <td>Cliente:</td>
                            <td>
                               @using (Html.BeginForm())
                               {
                                @Html.TextBox("dados", null, new { id = "cliente" });
                                <input type="submit" value="Procurar" />
                                }                            
                            </td>
```

Aonde eu estou tentando usar este autocomplete é na ultima linha do código com `id` **Cliente** e o `elemento html` `td` **Cliente**

A minha função Jquery está na primeira linha, ali no começo ! Com **GetClientesJson**

> A minha **`ControllerVendasPorProduto`** e a **`Action`** desta `View` e o `JsonResult`que retorna os dados para está `View` está assim:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Movimentacao_Total_Vendas(ReportsMovimentacaoTotalVendas dados)
        {
            ReportsData report = new ReportsData();
            report.MovimentacaoTotalVendas(dados);
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetClientesJson(string term)
        {
            ComboData BDGetClientesJson = new ComboData();
            List<string> nomes;

            nomes = BDGetClientesJson.Cliente().Where(x => x.CLIENTE.StartsWith(term)).Select(c => c.CLIENTE).ToList();

            return Json(nomes,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Bem, com tudo isso seguindo alguns passos por aí não está me retornando os dados no campo, nem mostrando os nomes dos Clientes enquanto usuário digita! Não me retorna nada, como disse primeira vez que utilizo esse `autocomplete`. Poderiam me dizer o que está errado e gostaria de uma solução por código com base no que mostrei !

Comment: A requisição está chegando no controller? Já tentou remover o HTTPPOST do cabeçalho do action?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa acabei de tirar o HTTPOST e nada!

Comment: As requisições não estão chegando certo?

Comment: Certo, exatamente!!

Comment: OK, poderia olhar o network do browser e ver se a requisição está dando 404?

Comment: Está dando, Get 200 -OK e Post 200 OK !

Comment: Se está dando 200 como podem não estar chegando na API?

Comment: Eu também não sei, o código está da maneira que coloquei ai neste post!

Comment: Se você acessar via `url` você retorna esses dados?

Answer (score 0):

Parece pouco, mas tente remover a "," apos a action

```
$("#cliente").autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("GetClientesJson",)',
    minLength: 1
});
```

E você tem certeza que adicionou o `jquery-ui` com a biblioteca para autocomplete ?
E sim, o  `[HttpPost]` não deve ser adicionado ao método, já que você não está especificando para ser via `Post`, pois o *deafult* é `Get`.

Se ainda não funcionar, monte um `JSON` na mão e adicione este ao *Source*. Pois assim você tem um ponto de partida para perceber onde está o erro, no server ou no cliente.